# From keyword not found where expected in PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below code:

```
v_SQL := '
-- ==========================================================
--  Main Unpivot Table -  To move years from column headings 
--  to rows values
-- ==========================================================

SELECT 
CAST(FieldYear AS Number) FieldYear
, FieldType
, CASE FieldValue 
WHEN '''' THEN NULL
ELSE CAST (FieldValue AS Number(38,8))
END FieldValue
FROM 
(SELECT ' || 
v_InsertType ||' AS FieldType
,Y1 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y2 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y3 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y4 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y5 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y6 as ' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || ' 
,Y7 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y8 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y9 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y10 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y11 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y12 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y13 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y14 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y15 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y16 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y17 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y18 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y19 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y20 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y21 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y22 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y23 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y24 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y25 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y26 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y27 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y28 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y29 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y30 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y31 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y32 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y33 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y34 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,Y35 as ' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '

FROM ' || 
v_tblInsertType || ') UP
UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldYear IN 
(' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
,' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '
)
)AS unpvt

Execute immediate v_SQL;
```

where v_FY0 is NUMBER(10);v_SQL NVarchar2(4000),v_InsertType VARCHAR2(4000); and v_OffSet Number(10); v_tblInsertType VARCHAR2(4000);

Upon executing, I get: v_FY0 =2018 and v_OffSet = 0;

Upon executing ,i am getting the error - ORA-00923: FROM Keyword not found where expected.

How to resolve this issue  and how to get this working.

Comment: Why don't you try outputting the results of the `v_sql` variable via dbms_output.put_line - then you can see what the query has been created as, and you should be able to spot the issue more easily.

Comment: Please try change `) AS unpvt` to `) unpvt`. Remove `AS`.

Comment: @PonderStibbons - that is actually the answer (rather than just a comment). Might as well post it as an Answer.

Comment: By the way `Execute immediate v_SQL;` won't be useful for a select query, unless you are storing the result somewhere. It isn't going to return any result. If you're using 12c and above, `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` may be useful with a dynamic cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code that gives me the required answer:

```
v_SQL := '
-- ==========================================================
--  Main Unpivot Table -  To move years from column headings 
--  to rows values
-- ==========================================================

SELECT 
     CAST(FieldYear AS Number) FieldYear
    , FieldType
    , CASE FieldValue 
        WHEN n'''' THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST (FieldValue AS Number(38,8))
      END FieldValue
FROM 
   (SELECT ' || 
    v_InsertType ||' AS FieldType
    ,Y1 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y2 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y3 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y4 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y5 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y6 as "' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y7 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y8 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y9 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y10 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y11 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y12 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y13 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y14 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y15 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y16 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y17 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y18 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y19 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y20 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y21 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y22 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y23 as  "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y24 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y25 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y26 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y27 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y28 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y29 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y30 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y31 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y32 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y33 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y34 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,Y35 as "' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"

  FROM ' || 
        v_tblInsertType || ') UP
UNPIVOT
   (FieldValue FOR FieldYear IN 
    ("' || CAST(v_FY0 - 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 - 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 - 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 - 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 - 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0     - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 1 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 2 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 3 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 4 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 5 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 6 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 7 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 8 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 9 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 10 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 11 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 12 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 13 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 14 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 15 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 16 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 17 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 18 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 19 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 20 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 21 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 22 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 23 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 24 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 25 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 26 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 27 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 28 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
    ,"' || CAST(v_FY0 + 29 - v_OffSet AS CHAR) || '"
)
) unpvt' ;

Execute immediate v_SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `as` in the `from` clause.

This query:

```
select * from (select dummy from dual) as tab
```

produces error `ORA-00933`. So simply remove `as`:

```
select * from (select dummy from dual) tab
```